# wp_list_pages - Using a Walker to customize output order

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm using wp_list_pages to create a navigation menu. I've run into a challenge with the menu order, though, and I am trying to figure out a way to take more control over the order of the menu.

Is it possible to customize the order of the wp_list_pages output using a Walker?

For example, I'd like to check if a given page in wp_list_pages results has a `post_meta` value of `page_x` and output that *first*, then do the same for another page, then, if none of the rules match, continue as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_pages( $args )` calls `get_pages( $args )`. You can filter the `get_pages()` output with a filter on `get_pages`.

Let’s say you call `wp_list_pages()` like this:

```
wp_list_pages(
    array(
        'please_filter_me' => TRUE
    )
);
```

You can sort the pages now with code like this (not tested):

```
add_filter( 'get_pages', function( $pages, $args ) {
    // not our query
    if ( empty ( $args['please_filter_me'] ) )
        return $pages;

    $out = $top = array();

    foreach ( $pages as $page )
    {
        if ( get_post_meta( $page->ID, 'my_key', TRUE ) )
            $top[] = $page;
        else
            $out[] = $page;
    }

    return $top + $out;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Been a long time since I had this question and I think I rolled a work-around.. I'm going to accept it for posterity, though, and reference back when I run into this again.